# Op-Amp / In-Amp (INA826) as voltage divider

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

We're trying to buffer (for safety, ruggedness and scaling reasons) the input of a µC via some instrumentation-amplifier : [INA826](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina826.pdf?ts=1606121659210&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

We had our eyes on a schematic in TI INA826 datasheet [image: TI app note]
The only problem is that we only have access to a asymetrical voltage supply (+5V) and also, we'd like to scale the op-amp output from 0-10V to 0-5V.

As I undestand it, we can just supply it with 0 / +5V and the output would be scaled to 0 / +2,3.

The one thing I don't understand though is that I thought the way to do it would be just to do a voltage divider followed by a unity op-amp circuit but that is not the case there...

Comment: *just to do a voltage divider followed by a unity op-amp circuit* Who says it has to be done like shown with the INA826 and that it cannot / should not be done with a voltage divider + unity gain buffer? I think it can be done that way as well and that would be **simpler** which I always prefer (never overcomplicate things). I see no reason to complicate things and use the INA826.

Comment: Ok, I'll go for a voltage-divider + non-inverting buffer op-amp then.
About your last sentence : *no reason to complicate things and use the INA826*
Do you mean that we should use the INA826 or we should *not* use it and go for maybe a simpler op-amp?

Comment: I would choose to **not** use the INA826 as it complicates things. Using an opamp would be easier. I see no reason to use the INA826 but if there are good reasons please mention them. And indeed as Andy mentions, you will probably need a **negative** supply rail to drive the opamp's output all the way down to 0 V.

Comment: I see, so best bet is to have a 0,5 to 4,5V voltage span (for example).
The INA826 being an instrumentation-oriented op-amp (or in-amp as they call it) with good CMRR, is there any argument apart from cost in favor of swapping it for a LM358 or any other vanilla op-amp?

Comment: *with good CMRR* Since (I think) your input signal is single ended (not differential) **why** would you need "good CMRR"? You're selecting on / mentioning criteria that **do not matter**.

Comment: that's fair, I mixed up things and well, being single-ended, CMRR is not gonna be of much use...
So the question that comes to light : **what criterias would matter** in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The one thing I don't understand though is that I thought the way to
> do it would be just to do a voltage divider followed by a unity op-amp
> circuit but that is not the case*

The input voltage range on your INA826 schematic goes from -10 volts to +10 volts and so you need an amplifier that has a negative supply voltage as well as a positive supply voltage to handle the negative range.

The 2.5 volt reference voltage (REF3225) on the REF pin then centralizes a 0 volt input voltage to produce +2.5 volts on the outputs hence, the output maps an input of -10 volts to an output of +0.2 volts AND, an input of +10 volts to an output of +4.8 volts.

> *we'd like to scale the op-amp output from 0-10V to 0-5V.*

As it current stands, the output range is +0.2 volts to +4.8 volts and would be acceptable for driving a 0 to 5 volt input range device.

> *The only problem is that we only have access to a asymetrical voltage
> supply (+5V)*

Well, that's a problem if you need a negative voltage input range to map properly to the output.

Comment: Hi Andy,

In our case, we only need a positive output range so the +5V power supply would do the job.
Thanks for clarifying the 2,5V reference voltage, that's what I thought but wans't completely sure.

One point stays blurry for me : why the 0,2V difference with the rail voltages? Is that an inherent property of the op-amps? What would be the name of that characteristic?

Thanks,

Comment: @VoltsAndNuts the INA826 can swing its output from the -Vs + 0.1 volts to the most +Vs - 0.15 volts so, if you are running from 5 volts and 0 volts then the output can only swing between +0.1 volts and +4.85 volts. So that's the best you can get from the INA826 on a single 5 volt rail but, the circuit design goes from +0.2 volts to +4.8 volts and that is a span that the INA is capable of with a comfort factor AND, also it has to feed some unknown circuit attached to the output AND, if it's an ADC then there's no guarantee it's input is 0 to 5 volts (despite what p1 of the DS might say).

Comment: Hi Andy,
One thing I don't quite get is that the part states "rail-to-rail output" but the voltage swiing is +0.1 / -0.15V 
Are these two different things?

Comment: Page 1 of a data sheet is reserved for the marketing hype. Most non R2R op-amps are lucky to get to within 2 volts of power rails so calling an op-amp R2R that gets to within 200 mV is par for the course in marketing hype @VoltsAndNuts

Comment: @VoltsAndNuts if you are happy with this answer, please consider [formally accepting it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png). If you still have queries then leave a comment. You've asked 14 questions now and you should get into the habit of formal acceptance of relevant answers (one per question where applicable). This helps other users focus on the answer that worked best for you. It is important BTW.